# How to pass edit Text value to Toast?

Tags: java, android

I've just started with android and I'm trying to make simple program to take string from user and display the result as `Toast`

```
EditText e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
final String result = e.getText().toString();
Button btx = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
btx.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
}
```

Now If I type anything in `editText` it's supposd to print that value but instead it's printing the default text value and even if I edit that it prints the same value

[image]
As you can see in the picture on pressing the button it shows "Name" on toast
and even upon changing it shows the same thing that is "Name". I want it too show the value that I typed later.
What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You store the text when you setup the views. Thats why you get the default text.

move

```
final String result=e.getText().toString();
```

into the `onClick`

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    final String result = e.getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

and it should get the text when the button is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

Reason is your variable `String result` is not taking latest value when button is clicked.

Try this:

```
  final EditText e = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
  Button btx = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
  btx.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         String result = e.getText().toString();
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
 }
```

Comment: Got it .Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

your requirement is show `EditText` Text in Toast

**first make `EditText` object as globle**

```
class ActivityClassFileName extend AppCompactActivity
{
    EditText ToastText;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activitylayout);

        //initialize EditText  object
        ToastText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        Button btx = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        btx.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) 
              {
                   //showing Toast
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ToastText.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: oh that's another way to do it Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you have to display toast outside of onclick,by creating new method.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText editText;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    editText=findViewById(R.id.editTextView);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String testString=editText.getText().toString();
            showToast(testString);
        }
    });
}

private void showToast(String str) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

}
```